# Why doesn't with Block do more than 1 thing?

Tags: python

```
with open('cool_csv.csv') as cool_csv_file:
  aa = cool_csv_file.read()
  print(aa)

  cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_file)
  for row in cool_csv_dict:
    print(row['Cool Fact'])
```

For the code above, only the first `print()` was printed, i.e. the content of the .csv file was printed, but it didn't print the Cool Facts in the `for` loop.
I have already come across this issue before where it seemed like I could only have 1 thing done in the `with` block. I doubt this is true, so I thought I'd ask here :)

Also, this might be related or not, but when does the `with` block close the connection to the file?

Comment: I think the indentation is ok since it would raise `NameError` on `cool_csv_file` otherwise. The reason is 100% to inspect in the object returned by `DictReader()`

Comment: `cool_csv_dict` is not a good name for that variable, because it is *not* a dictionary, as the name would imply. It is an object that, when iterated, returns a `dict` for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

When you do this:

```
  aa = cool_csv_file.read()
```

It consumes the entire input file.

Now there is nothing else for `DictReader` to read:

```
  cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_file)
  for row in cool_csv_dict:
```

The `for` loop iterates zero times and nothing is printed.

## Solutions

### Solution 1

Re-open the input file:

```
with open('cool_csv.csv') as cool_csv_file:
  aa = cool_csv_file.read()
  print(aa)

with open('cool_csv.csv') as cool_csv_file:
  cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_file)
  for row in cool_csv_dict:
    print(row['Cool Fact'])
```

### Solution 2

Rewind the input file:

```
with open('cool_csv.csv') as cool_csv_file:
  aa = cool_csv_file.read()
  print(aa)

  cool_csv_file.seek(0)

  cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_file)
  for row in cool_csv_dict:
    print(row['Cool Fact'])
```